# Floating Action Plus Sign Disappearing on Size Adjustment

Tags: java, android, xml, floating-action-button

I have a floating action button that I want to decrease in size. However, if I don't set the layout_width and layout_height to wrap_content, the button undesirably shrinks in size.

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:id="@+id/add_answers_button"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/actionRed"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_marginEnd="6dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
            android:elevation="0dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp"
            />
```

Result:

[image]

Shrink to 30dp width and height:

```
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:id="@+id/add_answers_button"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/actionRed"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_marginEnd="6dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
            android:elevation="0dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp"
            />
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're not suposed to but you might prefer to use an `ImageButton` instead.

Comment: How would that generate the floating action button image?

Comment: Using an image similar to the FAB as the `android:src` and, if needed, `android:background="@android:color/transparent"`